# Error empty CurlFile Object in PHP script for GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an small php script which is not working for GAE.. when executed php curlfile object is empty. This works well without using App engine but using wampserver.

What I intend to do is get a file from multipart request. Upload that file to another service which I have running on 3000 port which is specified in $url.

```
$url = "http://service:3000/tasks.test.payload/uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
        ConsoleLog($url);

        $fname = $_FILES['file']['name'];

        $file = new CURLFile(realpath($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
        var_dump($file);
        $post = array (
                  'file' => $file
                  );    

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");   
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data','Application: service-console-uploader'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);   
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
        $status = "false";

        if ($result === FALSE) {
            ConsoleLog("Error sending" . $fname);   
            $status = "false";          
        }else{
            ConsoleLog($result);
            $status = "true";
        }
```

I have added These 3 lines to php.ini file.. And Appengine Billing is enabled too.

`extension="curl.so"
extension=php_curl.dll
google_app_engine.enable_functions = "php_sapi_name, php_uname"`

The var_dump result I get is...

`object(CURLFile)#27 (3) { ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["mime"]=> string(0) "" ["postname"]=> string(0) "" }`

How can I solve this?